# Why after applying Canvas.Left to my Image it goes out from the canvas? (In WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

my canvas is 1920*1080 and I'm adding an image that its width is 200 and height is 200 too,
I want the image to go to the top right corner, and after setting the following code and running the application
I see that the image overflows the canvas:

```
            Image img = new Image();

            img.Source = SOURCE;
            img.Width = 200;
            img.Height = 200;

            screen.Canvas.Children.Add(img); // I have already created screen obj and a canvas before

            img.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 1720);
            img.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
```

after I checked it manually, I saw that if I put the Canvas.Left 1350 it fit the target,
but I can't understand why it happens

...................

And about the canvas parent:
it's in the window and I maximize the window at startup also I'm using the code below in its window constructor to maximize the canvas too:

```
var resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
Canvas.Width = resolution.Width; // i put the name of the canvas, Canvas :)
Canvas.Height = resolution.Height;
```

.................

another update:

I find out however I get the screen size 1920x1080 but the real size is 1536x864 so can anyone help how to get the real screen size? :)

Comment: Do you have your canvas inside something else is scaling it? Could you please add a minimal reproduction to your question?

Comment: Instead of assuming that the canvas is some particular size, why not calculate the image’s location based on what it actually is? Something like `img.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Canvas.Width - img.Width)` That doesn’t answer your question, but it might make it moot.

Comment: the point is I want to add lots of different images in the project with OpenFileDialog and place them in different places on screen with another approach @padeso

Comment: Clearly, the width isn't what you expect. You could use a viewbox to scale canvas and content. You need a fixed size on your canvas inside the viewbox inside the window or a cell of a grid in the window content. The viewbox can then scale it's content to fit and you can use fixed top and left positioning.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was I wasn't setting the actual width and height for my canvas,
when I use the resolution width and height, what I get is 1920x1080 but also I checked in my display setting that I have 125% scale so it makes the size 1536x864 so I got this number with RenderSize:

```
screen.Canvas.Width = screen.RenderSize.Width;
screen.Canvas.Height = screen.RenderSize.Height;
```

And also it's worth mentioning that if you use it in the constructor the RenderSize will be 0

[Why my resolution of Thinkpad T450s is 1536px width?](https://superuser.com/questions/1453912/why-my-resolution-of-thinkpad-t450s-is-1536px-width)